# Overloading java

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

I have a question about overloading in Java.
I have these functions in a class:

```
public class DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade extends DefaultCustomerFacade {

private MmfgUserService mmfgUserService;
private MmfgSessionService mmfgSessionService;
private UserProfileConfigurator userProfileConfigurator;

@Override
public void forgottenPassword(final String email) {
    Assert.hasText(email, "The field [email] cannot be empty");
    final CustomerModel customerModel = (CustomerModel) getMmfgUserService().getUserForEmail(email.toLowerCase(),
            null);
    // getUserService().getUserForUID(uid.toLowerCase(), CustomerModel.class);
    getCustomerAccountService().forgottenPassword(customerModel);
    }

public void forgottenPassword(final String email, final String uid) {
    Assert.hasText(email, "The field [email] cannot be empty");
    Assert.hasText(uid, "The field [uid] cannot be empty");
    final CustomerModel customerModel = (CustomerModel) getMmfgUserService().getUserForEmail(email, uid);
    // getUserService().getUserForUID(uid.toLowerCase(), CustomerModel.class);
    getCustomerAccountService().forgottenPassword(customerModel);
    }
}
```

I would call the *forgottenPassword(String, String)* function in another class in this way:

```
getCustomerFacade().forgottenPassword(form.getEmail(), form.getUid());
```

but I obtain an error at compilation time.

The *forgottenPassword(String)* function is an *@Override*. The second function instead is an overload. How I have to call the second function?

Thank you all, but I didn't ever use overloading in Java.

Comment: Did you have `forgottenPassword(String, String)` available in base class as well?

Comment: What error do you get and how did you declare the instance you are calling it on?

Comment: Override  is not the same as overload. Annotation @Override should be used if you implement interface or override parent implementation.

Comment: @akhil_mittal: probably not, which is why he mentions that one is an Override

Comment: @Natalia: I doubt that 's the problem. probably he declared the instance as an instance of the superclass, and tries to call the method that only exists in the child class. (the one with two parameters)

Comment: @Stultuske: Oh yea. My Bad. In that case object may not be of right type on which method is invoked.

Comment: The super class is a standard class. I can only override methods. I always do in this way. Now instead I have to overload the class: same name but different signature.

Comment: The super class has only the forgottenPassword(String) method

Comment: @Stultuske I use eclipse. Eclipse didn't show me the second function in the autocompletion. Only the first.

Comment: @sharkbait did you declare the instance as an instance of the superclass? That is most likely your problem.

Comment: @Stultuske the DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade class is an extension of the superclass. This is the wight way. What I have to do?

Comment: What is the return type of getCustomerFacade() method? Is it DefaultCustomerFacade? If yes, than compiler just doesn't know about existence of another overloaded method in DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade.

Comment: So I have to use the DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade?

Comment: @LevSivashov you're right! I have to use the DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade class in the controller and then I see the overloading function! Thank you! Write the answer! So everyone can know this problem and his solution! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question would have been much better, if you told us what the compile error was. Descriptions along the lines of "I get an error", "it doesn't work" leave readers unnecessary guesswork.

Comment: I didn't compile. I already wrote that I use Eclipse editor and the autocompletion doesn't show me the second method.

Comment: @sharkbait It's better not to use DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade. Please read my reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java if you have two methods with same names but different arguments lists, they are really two different methods. Like if you had two methods with different names. It makes no difference for the compiler. The arguments lists differ => these are two different methods.

In your case you have a base class/interface DefaultCustomerFacade with one method declared in it. You have an implementation DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade that overrides that declared method. When you overload that method in DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade, it will behave the same way as if you added any other method with different name. There's no way for compiler to know that the method is overloaded in the implementation of DefaultCustomerFacade.

So you have two choices:

1. Overload the method in the base class/interface: just declare both methods in DefaultCustomerFacade.
2. Use DefaultMmfgCustomerFacade instead of DefaultCustomerFacade as a return type of your getCustomerFacade() method.

The first one is more preferable of course, because you will be able to change the implementation without modifying/recompiling client code. And it's generally a good rule to use interfaces instead of concrete implementations where possible. This will make your code less coupled and easier to maintain.

Comment: great! Thank you @Lev Sivashov

Comment: I know the best is modify the super class. But this class is a standard class in Hybris that I can't modify... I can only extend the superclass. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that forgottenPassword(String) is a function in DefaultCustomerFacade that you are overriding. To override, you need to match the function signature exactly.

I would suggest choosing a different name for both functions, and have the overriding function call the other one.

eg:

- @override forgottenPassword(String) (calls resetPassword)
- resetPassword(String)
- resetPassword(String, String)

Comment: I DON'Twant override. I want overload :) the override works! the second function instead no.

Comment: I don't think that you can overload an overridden method, which is what you are trying to do. Overloading a method means creating two different implementations of a method that take different inputs. However, when you override a method, it must match the method exactly, both in name, return type, and input. Overloading breaks this matching, generating the error.